# knockoutjs global rate-limit

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, throttling, rate-limiting

Is there any way how to globally delay any KnockoutJS processing / redrawing as long as I keep changing any observable in the model?

Basically, knockout should observe all changes to all observables and if there is no change to any observable for a period of 50ms only then it can start processing the changes.

Comment: This can help. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no global way to throttle / rate-limit / delay. You can only rate limit individual observables.